# Understanding signed numbers in Verilog

Tags: verilog

For my Verilog code, I am trying to define a 64 bit array, like this

```
input signed [63:0] var_name
```

This array is broken up such that it is 8 bytes, each with a width of 8 bits.

I am wondering how Verilog handles mathematics in this case.  If I want to sum up all the different "bytes" of `var_name`, I try to do it like this:

```
module sum(var_name, sum);
input signed [63:0] var_name;
output reg signed [9:0] sum;

always @ * begin
sum = 0;
for(i = 0; i<8; i = i+1)
   begin
   sum = sum + var_name[8*(i+1)-1 -:8];
   end
end
endmodule
```

(note, this code may not be proper, it is just an illustration).

Does Verilog treat each 8-bit word as a signed integer? Or does Verilog only consider the entire word `var_name` as a signed word?

Thanks a lot for reading.  I hope my question is clear enough! If not, please ask questions about it. :)

Comment: Why don't you write a testbench and try it?

Comment: Hi Elliot,

To be honest, it's been a while since I've used a testbench.  I am using Xilinx System Generator, so it is block-based design. I got it to work though.  I used an intermediate step in order to break up the input into a packed array register. This seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

Only the entire declaration as a whole is considered signed. Selecting a bit or part-select (even if it selects the entire range) would be considered unsigned. That's because the base element data type of the array (`reg`) is unsigned.

SystemVerilog allows you to layer your types so that you could take a signed 8-bit type and pack it into a signed 64-bit declarations.

```
typedef logic signed [7:0] byte_t;
byte_t signed [7:0] var_name;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  If I have an intermediate step that uses a register to break it up into a packed array form, would the signed work then? I can't use SystemVerilog for my purposes.

Comment: Yes, you can always make intermediate variable assignments to get the effect of a cast.

Comment: Hi Dave,

It seemed to fix my issue.  It seems like an ugly workaround that wastes a bit of memory, but hopefully it doesn't waste too much.

Comment: That what you get for sticking with a 30 year old language.

Comment: All I gotta say is... Blame Xilinx.